# I have a PDO connection failiure in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

So I am trying to migrate but I have this exception

[image]

My database connection is correct both in the env file and In the database.php file, what might be the problem?

Comment: can run this command `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: I tried it, did not work

Answer (score 0):

### You are using remotely connection

Try to use `ip address` instead of `domain` and add your ip address into the MySQL connection, otherwise giving you (*) all ip address.

### Allow your ip address to access mysql database

giving permission try this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

after giving grant use this command:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

for more information, read this [article](https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/).